# ONSEN UI applying different color to each list

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I have 3 lists and I want to apply different color to each list,
how can I do this?

```
<ons-list class="one">
  <ons-list-item>
    ...
  </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>


<ons-list class="two">
  <ons-list-item>
    ...
  </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>

<ons-list class="three">
  <ons-list-item>
    ...
  </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [modifier](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-list.html#attributes) attribute.

```
<ons-list modifier="one">
    <ons-list-item />
</ons-list>
```

And then in your CSS, you can apply styles to the list and list-items:

```
.list--one {

}

.list--one .list__item {
}
```